# The [strongswan] tag is a weak tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

47 questions tagged with [strongswan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strongswan), all of them off topic. Can we burniate this tag?

Comment: I voted to close several already but I ran out of close votes and downvotes; if other people can filter on that in the close vote queue, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Typical casual speciesism, afraid of swans that are proud and strong.

Comment: Seriously though, while many of them would certainly belong on Server Fault,  I'm not *entirely* sure those questions are all off-topic? Like [this one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878584/strongswan-connect-to-mysql) Possibly not a great question, but not sure whether off topic

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You found 47 questions that are off-topic, and your solution is to remove the tag and leave the questions?

Remove the questions if they're off-topic. If there are no questions, then the tag goes away on its own.

Please don't use [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request)s for problems [that are not inherent in the tags themselves or how they are used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate).

Comment: Fair enough, I probably should've tagged this as a cleanup request instead.